# Make a method return an object of a subclass

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, mypy

I want to provide method to a class, so that it gets transformed into a special case, represented by a subclass. I'm not sure, however what is the best way to do it.

Here is an illustrative example:

```py
class Vector(pd.Series):
    def normalize(self) -> "NormalizedVector":
        result: "NormalizedVector" = self / sum(self)  # type:ignore
        return result

class NormalizedVector(Vector):
    pass
```

There are issues with this implementation, though:

- `isinstance(vector.normalize(), NormalizedVector)` will be `False`
- (relatedly) the `# type: ignore` annotation is required for static type checking

So my question is: *what is a clean way of achieving this?*

The alternative I found was using dynamic allocation:

```py
class Vector(pd.Series):
    pass

class NormalizedVector(Vector):
    pass

def normalize_vector(self: Vector) -> NormalizedVector:
    return NormalizedVector(self / sum(self))

Vector.normalize = normalize_vector
```

However:

- I find it makes the code much less readable
- I'm afraid to be messing with the end method metadata, such as `__name__`

Comment: `Vector.normalize` doesn't contain enough information to create a `NormalizedVector` without an explicit conversion.

Comment: What guarantee is there that a `NormalizedVector` instance is, in fact, normalized?

Comment: ... and stays normalized.

Comment: I don't recall I would have distinguished between Vector and NormalizedVector in math classes. Everything is a Vector. Some of them are normalized, other are not. With a bit of math, you can make a vector normalized, but it's still a Vector. Why do you want to make that distinction?

Comment: This is a simple example. In practice here the NormalizedVector could augment its parent's methods, like `__init__`, to ensure it is and stays normalized. But this is not really my question...

Comment: Honnestly, I find the second way as least as much readable and Pythonic that the first one... And I cannot understand what you mean with *messing with the end method metadata*.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I want to make a distinction so I can accurately annotate functions that expect a normalized vector. I can then benefit from static analysis and avoid sparkling internal functions (for which I control the inputs) with runtime checks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A type hint alone doesn't cause a value to *become* the hinted type. You need to *create* an instance. Your second approach works because you actually created that instance. The explicit assignment is unnecessary.

```
class Vector(pd.Series):
    def normalize(self) -> "NormalizedVector":
        return NormalizedVector(self / sum(self))

class NormalizedVector(Vector):
    pass
```

Comment: I forgot that I could use a yet-to-be-defined class in the function body ‍♂️. This answers my question perfectly.

Comment: I still don't think that this is good OO design. Each time you do something similar, you will create a new class and modify the base class. That violates OCP and SRP, doesn't it? And the NormalizedVector will likely violate LSP, because it can't be multiplied. This might be a case for FCoI  @Thrastylon

Comment: @ThomasWeller Whether `NormalizedVector` should be a subclass of `Vector` is an entirely separate question. The fact that it is a subclass here is only relevant for explaining why `NormalizedVector` couldn't be defined before `Vector`. (And as it turns out, the order isn't relevant at all to the solution.)

Comment: @Thrastylon Right: when `normalize` is *defined*, `NormalizedVector` is just a free variable. The name doesn't need to be defined until the function is actually *called*. At that point, the name needs to resolve to something or a `NameError` will be raised.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Multiplying normalized and non-normalized vectors is only a problem if you expect the result to be normalized.